# php str_replace adding unwanted spaces around HTML tags

Tags: php, html

I'm creating an email body (PHPMailer) text by using str_replace

for example

```
$template = str_replace('%customer_name%', '<b style="color: #505151;">SOME NAME</b>', $template);
```

but for some reason this is adding an space between < and b

```
< b style="color: #505151;">SOME NAME</b>
```

and in the email its of course showing this in a very ugly way.

Is there a way to fix this?

EDIT:

```
// Fetch the customer details
$_customer = $customer->fetch_by_order_id($order->getId());
// Fetch the email html template
$template = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../templates/email-template.html');
// replace customer details to template
$template = str_replace('${customer-name}', $_customer->getName(), $template);
$template = str_replace('${customer-address}', $_customer->getAddress() .', '. $_customer->getZip() . ' ' . $_customer->getCity(), $template);
etc..
```

Comment: When do you get the space? In `$template` already or in the final email (if that, is it before sending already or after delivery only)?

Comment: At localhost when i am printing the $template out its working as it should. Before and after sending the mail. And this is not happening in every case or this can appear in some other str_replace method.

Comment: Can yo edit this information into your question with as many details as you can?

Comment: Not a fix, but a possible work around could be to add this afterwards.. `$template = "<" . substr($template, 2);` to remove the space